# Smooth animation CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm having a problem to keep an animation running "smooth" each time a new line of text is added.

The main problem here is that I want the speed of the animation to be constant, no matter how many lines are added. In order to do so the code is recalculating the speed each time a new line is added.

The problem is that when this happens the whole block of text "Jumps".

I was thinking that maybe the whole method I'm using wont give me the result I'm looking for so the question is.

Is there a fix or better alternative to achieve this?

I have a codepen with the example (Each time you press any key a new line will be added so we can simulate the behavior)

https://codepen.io/MrAmericanMike/pen/GeyZJg

Thanks a lot.

```js
let marqueeContainer = document.getElementById("marqueeContainer");

let marqueeText = document.createElement("p");
marqueeContainer.appendChild(marqueeText);

document.addEventListener("keydown", addText);

let wordCount = 1;

function addText(){
  let things = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
  let thing = wordCount + " - " + things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)];
  marqueeText.innerHTML += thing + "<br/>";
  calcSpeed(50);
  wordCount++;
}

function calcSpeed(speed) {
    // Time = Distance/Speed
    var spanSelector = document.querySelector('#marqueeContainer p');
    var spanLength = spanSelector.offsetHeight;
    var timeTaken = spanLength / speed;
    spanSelector.style.animationDuration = timeTaken + "s";
}
```

```css
#marqueeContainer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 33, 0.5);
    white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

#marqueeContainer p {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 200px;
    animation: marqueeContainer linear infinite;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

@keyframes marqueeContainer {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(0, -105%); }
}
```

```html
<div id="marqueeContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in browsers caused by the way they calculate percentage of progress (and, in this case, the position) according on the animation duration. This means that when you change the animation duration you are also changing the percentage of progress and your animation "jumps". I don't think there is a CSS solution, you should use a JS only solution with `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: The source of the issue is that every time a line is added, the speed of the animation is changed.  When this happens at any point during the animation the current keyframe percent of the animation will be different from what it previously was.  For example, 55% with a duration of 1s is different from 55% of 2 seconds.

Comment: You need to keep your `height` constant, try adding `height: 200px` to `#marqueeContainer p`, that'll work but it'll fail when your content gets bigger than 400px, this is just a start.

Comment: Thanks. A friend also recommend me to look into requestAnimationFrame and it was the solution. We worked on this changes for the code, and it's working really nice and smooth.
https://codepen.io/MrAmericanMike/pen/JzMRWM
Thanks everyone for the answers.